# Hierarchical or flat domain-model-graph?

Tags: c#, data-structures, graph, domain-driven-design, entity

I'm building a custom general purpose domain model for some assorted c#-projects. The issue I'm struggling with now is the choice of model structure. Either I do a hierachical model with parent, children, ancestors etc or a flat more graph-like structure. With hierarchical I mean where I can write Entity.Parent and get the parent and graph where I have links instead of relationships.

It's a great deal simpler and less error prone to do a flat graph. You could for instance load individual entities one at a time in some random order without having to assemble them in a correct structure.

But the concept of a hierarchical domain is also pretty attractive. It's nicely structured and organized. A great benifit with a hierarchical domain is that you can inherit properties from a parent or ancestor. You can for instance inherit deletion-state into the descendants. Having a flat graph this wouldn't be as easy. Also this requires all ancestors to be loaded for all entities at all times which of course is a down-side.

So my question is what other benifits there are with a hierarchical domain? I couln't come up with any more than inheriting properties from ancestors and perhaps messaging within the graph; For instance if an entity would like to react to a change in a descendant entity. Any more benifits? I'm not sure I really need the above so If there aren't any more great benifits I think I go for the flat structure anyway because it's so much simpler to work with.

Comment: There is no correct answer to this. Both approaches have pros and cons, to give an accurate answer we are going to need some information about the real domains that you are attempting to model.

Comment: But what more benifits are there of making the effort of building and maintaining a valid and correct hierachical tree structure of all entities in the domain-state? I mean it's a lot more complex to create a hierarchical graph, so there should be many reason why this is good thing to do.

Comment: I think the assertion that "It's more complex therefore it must be a good thing to do" is deeply flawed. We should be striving for the simplest solution to an existing problem. Not creating complex solutions and then looking for problems that they solve.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged DDD I would ask what is the aggregate root for the given domain and let that make your decision.

Comment: I guess DDD implies a hierarchical structure. With a graph structure I wouldn't have any aggregates. I'm not sure I understand what you ment though. What are the benifits or having aggregates? Accept being able to delete or detach a whole aggregate/branch of the domain-state? (I'm not trying to implement all aspects of DDD, or perhaps none.)

Comment: Well that was not completely true maybee. I could have aggregates in a graph too I guess. But they wouldn't necessarily have to be structured as a valid tree with parent, children etc.